# How to set multiple response from multiple table in C# into a single model so that I can fetch into html table using angular js 'ng-repeat'?

Tags: c#, angularjs

```
[HttpPost]
        [Route("getReportAttendance")]
        public IHttpActionResult getReportAttendance(AttendanceReport data)
        {
           
                BadgesWebApiClient client = new BadgesWebApiClient();

                 var  matrix = client.getReportAttendance(data);
                 var  matrix1 = client.getReportObservation(data);
                 var  matrix2 = client.getReportAttendancedata(data);
                 var  matrix3 = client.getReportAssignment(data);
                 return Ok();
         }
```

From matrix, matrix1, matrix2 and matrix3 I am getting the multiple response as a form of an array.

```
var report = new ReportGenerate()
{
}
```

And this is my model, and I want to bind all the response to this single model.
How can I do this?

Comment: Is this really related to the <sql> _language_? I see no SQL above, do you expect SQL in the answer?

Comment: No, I just edited that.

Comment: Could you please provide more data about the types of your code? You can probably do that by creating an anonymous object with 4 fields {Matrix1 = matrix1} and disassembling that object on the other side with JS. There are other ways of handling this problem, but the amount of data provided does not allow one to come up with an answer.

Comment: Yes, I have solved the issue by doing this.
`
var report = new AttendanceReport()
                {
                    getReportAttendance = matrix.getReportAttendance,
                    getReportObservation = matrix1.getReportObservation,
                    getReportAttendancedata = matrix2.getReportAttendancedata,
                    getReportAssignment = matrix3.getReportAssignment
                 };
                return Ok(report);
`